# what css tech to use for rich column / row nested content boxes?

Tags: css, flexbox

What I need are content boxes that display lots of small separate pieces of data as well as small buttons. In a large rectangular box I need many columns, rows, nested inside each other with precise sizes, layouts, and some ability to stretch and shrink a bit and maybe wrap when the page width is under 1024px.

I've done this with flexbox but it's divs inside of divs inside of divs until it seems it is just wrong to be doing this so I'm looking at other options.

I don't know a ton of css so I'm trying to narrow down what set of techniques I should be using and need to learn to accomplish this.

Something with absolute positioning and everything laid out to the pixel?

Or should I continue on with flexbox?

Comment: Flexbox is great for things like this but I would look into some table libraries that may have the functionality you are looking for. React Table is a pretty good one.

Comment: I had stick with flex if i were you. Alternatively you can have a relatively positioned container with the bunch of absolute postions divs inside . If you can endure the individual positioning then you can go with the absolute positioning. Note, you can group few divs in a single containers n flex. So i don't see why it gets annoying unless you styled them individually.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Flexbox is made for one dimensional layouts and Grid is made for two
dimensional layouts. I suggest you to try `grid`, its better on lower version of browsers rather than `flex` display. Someone already made the comparison about performance, rather than i rewrite what he said maybe you want to look it by your self [here](https://blogs.igalia.com/jfernandez/2015/06/24/performance-on-grid-layout/)

Maybe you want to see [this codepen](https://codepen.io/rachelandrew/pen/YqqdXL) and [this demos](https://gridbyexample.com/examples/)

Comment: "Grid is made for two dimensional layouts". I looked in the demos and found exactly what I needed, thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Standard Options:

- Old Approach: Use a mixture of tables and ul elements with display 'inline block'. Many if not most websites use this really, as developers have had to deal with this for years. If you want your site to be pixel perfect and responsiveness doesn't really matter, this option might actually be best.
- Flexbox (You are already using it): You use display flex on the 'grid' container element and try to arrange the children it contains. Flexbox is meant to be used to make your elements responsive/flexible, but it is not a grid by itself. (it's one dimensional)
- CSS Grid: The newest alternative vanilla CSS offers. Simple to use. It behaves very similar to the Bootstrap grid which a lot of people are used to using now. But you first have to define the arrangement of the columns and rows in the CSS.

Libraries:

- Bootstrap: Kind of an industry standard now. You'd want to use the fixed grid and not the fluid grid if you want your elements to be pixel perfect.
- PureCSS: Lightweight library with helper CSS classes you can use.
- Flexbox Grid: Kind of the same as PureCSS, but only focused on the grid element.
- ... there are many more. Someone suggested React-Table, which is great if your project is React based.